# JQuery animations and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this code:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wtf is that</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">

    {{test}}
    <br />
    <button ng-click="set()">set</button>
    <button ng-click="setTimeout()">setTimeout</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.test = false;
  $scope.set = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
                $scope.test = !$scope.test;
        }, 1000);
  };
  $scope.setTimeout = function() {
        $('body').slideUp(1000, function () {
            $('body').slideDown(1000, function () {
                $scope.test = !$scope.test;
        console.log($scope.test);
                console.log('done');
            });
        });
  };
});
```

Why `$scope` variables doesn't change when I changing after the animation ends?

In timeout:

```
  $scope.set = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
            $scope.test = !$scope.test;
    }, 1000);
};
```

All working ok.

Comment: Angular and Angular js are different please tag correctly

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.test = false;
    $scope.set = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                console.log("update time clicked");
                $scope.test = !$scope.test;
            });
        }, 1000);
    };
    $scope.setTimeout = function() {
        $('body').slideUp(1000, function() {
            $('body').slideDown(1000, function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.test = !$scope.test;
                });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wtf is that</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">

    {{test}}
    <br />
    <button ng-click="set()">set</button>
    <button ng-click="setTimeout()">setTimeout</button>

</body>

</html>
```

you need to use $scope.$apply because
when you change an AngularJS model outside (from external JavaScript) - you need to use $scope.$apply() to AngularJS know that model has modified.

Comment: But {{test}} still displays false

Comment: Take a look on @eKimiya answer.

Comment: i have added timeout before but the problem occurs because i have not added  $scope.$apply that is why not working

Comment: its ok, just give few words why we need $apply, not just working solution. Its not good practice in SO :)

Comment: please ask  polak polkovski  my answer not give him real time changethat is the reason i have changed answer

Comment: @MaximShoustin i will keep in mind and update the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153530/discussion-between-programmer21-and-maxim-shoustin).

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery animations are running outside of Angular scope. You need to specify to Angular that your scope has changed with :

```
$scope.$apply();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/hfIlZzBXo9hTmIvJ15oa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, Angular doesn't know about DOM manipulations.  To trigger digest cycle you can wrap `$scope.test = !$scope.test;` with `$timeout` to make it work:

```
$('body').slideUp(1000, function () {
        $('body').slideDown(1000, function () {
           $timeout(function(){
            $scope.test = !$scope.test;
            });
        });
    });
```

<kbd>[Fixed Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpggCU9RoS2tRjTNA37X?p=preview)</kbd>